# Render views file in yii framework

Tags: yii

In yii framework, i want to render view file index.php in folder views look like this:

```
views/
--layouts/
--site/
index.php <!--run file index.php here-->
```

Somebody can tell me?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$this->render('index');
```

in the **required action of your Site Controller**

If you want to pass any variables to your **index.php file** then you can send it as an array in the second argument of your **render() method** like

```
$this->render('index',array('name'=>'tion'));
```

then you can use it in your **index.php** like
**$name**

Answer (score 1):

As I know you can not render view file outside the "views" directory.

Try to

`$this->render('//index')`